# Insert into Table Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis

I have the following Data flow [image]

I need to insert rows into flat files and table using ado.net connector 
[image]

and I always get this error

```
[ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'"utilisateur_id", "nom", "prenom", "type" at line 1

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error 
code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error 
is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more 
information about the failure.
```

I've tried to search for an answer and found this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis.aspx

But I didn't really know how to fix it. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your mysql query here?

Comment: Change the destination column to a text or string type. This will allow the job to succeed. You can examine the data that is being transferred and determine how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Odbc Data Provider and save yourself a headache.

Comment: using Odbc Data Provider ,I get this error : [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input 
"ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data
 Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Those double-quote marks may be the problem.  MySQL is a bit different from the other databases, but I think it will accept a statement without the double-quote marks.

Answer (score 2):

Start the MySQL Server and login to it. Run the following commands as shown in the figure. By setting the mode to 'ANSI' makes the syntax more standard like as MySQL can cater to clients using other SQL modes. This is why the above error is returned although the syntax itself appears correct. In fact a create statement run on command line to create a table directly on MySQL could not create a table and returned an error when SSIS was used to create the same table.

RUN THE FOLLOWING...

```
mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;

+-------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global sql_mode='ANSI';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ANSI |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

After running the above statements, build the BI project and execute the package. This time the execution is will be successful.

One more thing:

Make sure you set **ValidateExternalMetada on ADO NET Destination to false** or else you will be in hell hole for more than 3 days

Answer (score 0):

How long is this takeing to run?  How much data are we talking about here?

```
code 0xC020844B normaly means that that the connection to the database has timed out.
```